# Pre-positive definite functions?

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, fourier-analysis

A function $f(x,y)$ is positive definite if matrices $( f(x_i, x_j) )_{i, j \in F}$ are positive definite for all finite index sets $F$. This is frequently hard or impossible to check given some function $f$, which leads me to the question: what if these matrices are positive definite only for $\# F \leq n$ with some fixed $n$ and all choices of $\{ x_i \}$? Let's say that functions satisfying this condition are $n$-preposdef. Does this property make sense? And if yes, has it been studied before? I haven't found anything, so maybe the notion is stupid.

I am asking this question because this $n$-preposdef property may even be checked numerically by minimizing consecutive determinants with respect to the parameters.

Comment: I don't know whether this exactly has been studied, but the "matrix version" of this has been studied: given a $k \times k$ matrix, you can ask whether or not every principal $n \times n$ submatrix of it is positive semidefinite (i.e., we only care about index sets of size at most $n$). If they are, we say that the matrix is "$n$-locally positive semidefinite" (see [arXiv:2012.04031](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04031) for example).